# Do search engines ignore or penalize well known quotes when they are properly marked up <q> or <blockquote>?

Tags: seo, html, duplicate-content

I want to add quotes from artists on my site. I know that I can put these quotes into `q` or `blockquote` elements.

Do search engines ignore these quotes? I do not want these quotes to affect my sites rank in a negative way.

Is there an SEO difference between quotes, blockquotes and pullquotes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Search engines won't ignore or penalise quotations, provided they're accompanied by original content (i.e. the content is not wholly or substantially a duplicate of pre-existing web content).

In fact, proper use of `<q>` and `<blockquote>` elements (with `<cite>` where appropriate) is arguably a good way of indicating to search engines that you're being honest about material you've taken from elsewhere.

There's no SEO difference between `<q>` and `<blockquote>`, but they do have slightly different purposes. I'd encourage you to consult the latest version of [the HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/).

A pull quote is a visual style and not syntactically distinct from `<blockquote>` in terms of document structure, so there's no special HTML markup for those.

Comment: thank you for the fast and detailed answer. Very helpful.

Comment: Quote away :). Just make sure you're providing enough unique & valuable context of your own too!

Comment: `blockquote`/`q` shouldn’t be used for pull quotes, unless you pull quote a quote ;) -- [`aside`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/sections.html#the-aside-element) should be used for it:  "The element can be used for typographical effects **like pull quotes** […]"